# How can I copy an SSAS cube from one project to another?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssas, ssdt-bi

I have two Analysis Services projects. I want to copy a cube from project A to project B. How can I copy an SSAS cube from one project to another?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, it seems that you want to move cube to another project, you could refer to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cae18813-c219-4cb5-a25d-7c04e9bafa30/can-we-addtransfer-a-cube-from-one-bids-project-solution-to-another-bids-project-solution?forum=sqlanalysisservices)  for details.

In addition, if you want to deploy cube to another server, you also could refer to [Deploy a Created Cube to a Different SSAS Server](https://help.zaptechnology.com/Zap%20CubeXpress/CurrentVersion/Content/Topics/HowTo/ImportCreatedCube.htm)  for details.

Zoe